# Join list conditionally

Tags: python, conditional-operator

I am trying to join items of a list using the `or` condition. sth like this

```
my_list =['aa','bg','cr','dn']

if 'a' in or.join(my_list):
  #do something
```

I would appreciate any helping hand.

Thank you

Comment: What output are you wanting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any('a' in x for x in my_list):
    # do sth
```

Note that `'aa' or 'bg' or ...` evaluates to the first truthy operand, here `'aa'`. So

```
if 'a' in ('aa' or 'bg' or ...):
```

is equivalent to:

```
if 'a' in 'aa':
```

which is most likely not what you want. What you are really trying:

```
if 'a' in 'aa' or 'a' in 'bg' or ...:
```